# How do I stop AWS ec2 instances from automatically restarting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS free tier account.  I have a number of ec2 instances in us west 1 and 2 which I have been trying to terminate.

However, every time I do this from the console, the instances automatically restart.  How do I stop them from restarting?

Comment: How did you try that? with cli or console?

Comment: EC2 instances don't restart automatically by default. Also, if you are terminating an instance, then it isn't restarting, it is being replaced by a new instance. It sounds like you have the instances in an auto-scaling group. You would need to delete the auto-scaling group first, or set the desired instances in the group to `0`.

Comment: See if there are persistent SPOT requests open to the instances.

Answer (score 0):

Suspend 'Launch'&'Terminate' process under Auto Scale Group
[AWS EC2 Auto Scaling User guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-suspend-resume-processes.html)

Also it could be build Launch configuration/ Launch templates, so these needs to update accordingly